# Вычислить продолжительность анимации SVG в Delphi

Tags: delphi, парсер, xml, svg

Есть анимации в формате SVG. Задача состоит в том, чтобы высчитать её продолжительность. Поскольку анимация может быть бесконечной, мне необходимо высчитать время одного цикла воспроизведения анимации.
По своей структуре файл анимации SVG имеет структуру XML.
Проверял несколько выборочно на XML-валидаторах, структура правильная. Мне нужно распарсить файл анимации таким образом чтобы получить в итоге наибольшее значение времени.
Задача не совсем простая. В файле анимации есть два тэга, которые отвечают за время, это: begin - начало и dur - длительность.
Суть в том, что первого тэга может не быть, и по умолчанию его значение нужно будет ставить равным 0. Также он может он присутствовать, и иметь любое значение.

[image: Таблица тегов]

Вот что должно в итоге получиться, мне нужно получить в итоге одну наибольшую цифру, которая получится в результате, она и будет являться длительностью одного цикла анимации.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="450px" height="279px" viewBox="0 0 450 279" enable-background="new 0 0 450 279" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_1">

    <line fill="none" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="9" y1="217" x2="81" y2="172" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="217" to="217" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="217;244;244;208;208;217;217" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="172" to="172" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="172;235;235;217;217;172;172" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="81" y1="172" x2="153" y2="181" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="172" to="172" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="172;235;235;217;217;172;172" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="153" to="153" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="153;99;99;144;144;153;153" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="153" y1="181" x2="225" y2="145" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="153" to="153" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="153;99;99;144;144;153;153" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="145" to="145" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="145;63;63;108;108;145;145" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="225" y1="145" x2="297" y2="55" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="145" to="145" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="145;63;63;108;108;145;145" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="55" to="55" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="55;45;45;63;63;55;55" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="297" y1="55" x2="369" y2="72" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="55" to="55" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="55;45;45;63;63;55;55" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="72" to="72" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="72;63;63;99;99;72;72" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="369" y1="72" x2="441" y2="45" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="72" to="72" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="72;63;63;99;99;72;72" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="45" to="45" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="45;36;36;54;54;45;45" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="9" cy="217" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="217" to="217" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="217;244;244;208;208;217;217" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="81" cy="172" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="172" to="172" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="172;235;235;217;217;172;172" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="153" cy="181" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="153" to="153" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="153;99;99;144;144;153;153" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="225" cy="145" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="145" to="145" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="145;63;63;108;108;145;145" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="297" cy="55" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="55" to="55" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="55;45;45;63;63;55;55" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="369" cy="72" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="72" to="72" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="72;63;63;99;99;72;72" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6C54C9" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="441" cy="45" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="45" to="45" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="45;36;36;54;54;45;45" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</g>


<g id="Layer_2">
    <line fill="none" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="9" y1="181" x2="81" y2="208" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="181" to="181" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="181;171;171;190;190;181;181" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="208" to="208" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="208;162;162;190;190;208;208" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="81" y1="208" x2="153" y2="127" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="208" to="208" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="208;162;162;190;190;208;208" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="127" to="127" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="127;117;117;90;90;127;127" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="153" y1="127" x2="225" y2="82" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="127" to="127" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="127;117;117;90;90;127;127" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="82" to="82" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="82;127;127;145;145;82;82" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="225" y1="82" x2="297" y2="118" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="82" to="82" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="82;127;127;145;145;82;82" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="118" to="118" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="118;108;108;127;127;118;118" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="297" y1="118" x2="369" y2="45" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="118" to="118" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="118;108;108;127;127;118;118" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="45" to="45" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="45;27;27;36;36;45;45" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <line fill="none" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="369" y1="45" x2="441" y2="36" opacity=".65">
        <animate attributeName="y1" from="45" to="45" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="45;27;27;36;36;45;45" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="y2" from="36" to="36" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="36;12;12;18;18;36;36" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </line>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="9" cy="181" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="181" to="181" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="181;171;171;190;190;181;181" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="81" cy="208" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="208" to="208" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="208;162;162;190;190;208;208" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="153" cy="127" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="127" to="127" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="127;117;117;90;90;127;127" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="225" cy="82" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="82" to="82" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="82;127;127;145;145;82;82" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="297" cy="118" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="118" to="118" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="118;108;108;127;127;118;118" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="369" cy="45" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="45" to="45" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="45;27;27;36;36;45;45" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>

    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B450FF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="441" cy="36" r="6">
        <animate attributeName="cy" from="36" to="36" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="36;12;12;18;18;36;36" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</g>
</svg>
```

[SVG анимация](https://svgmagic.io/images/animated-graphs.svg)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RootNode: IXMLNode;
  doc: IXmlDocument;
  I: Integer;
  dt: string;
begin
  XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile('beer.svg');
  XMLDocument1.Active := true;
  RootNode := doc.ChildNodes.FindNode('svg');
  for I := 0 to XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    dt := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[I].ChildNodes['animate'].Attributes['dur'].text;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(dt);
  end;
  XMLDocument1.Active := False;
end;
```

Comment: План у вас есть, отлично. В чем конкретно затруднения?

Comment: Не могу получить значения атрибутов begin и dur

Comment: Конкретнее, пожалуйста. Вы можете прочитать XML? распарсить? получить значения? написать логику работы с ними?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то SVG это root-node. Нужные мне значения находятся в childnode "animate" (хотя он в других файлах может быть другим). Прописываю полный путь для получения значения атрибута из нужного мне нода, но в итоге получаю пустое значение. С XML у меня не очень дружелюбные отношения.

Comment: *Прописываю полный путь для получения значения атрибута из нужного мне нода* - код в студию, пожалуйста!

Comment: я думаю в этом случае можно плюнуть на парсер XML и взять https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Regular_Expressions По любому RegEx может выступить альтернативой (вытаскиваем все нужные строки, конвертируем в числа, складываем что нужно в массивы - муторно, но не сложно).